# MySQL count maximum number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select the classes with maximum enrollment in each department from a table with the following structure:

Courses:  cid, dept, name

Enrollment:  cid, sid

The idea would be to count all the enrollments in each class, and find the maximum in each department.  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with the maximum-count combination.

My query was going to look something like:

```
 SELECT c.name, MAX(COUNT(*) FROM Enrollment E WHERE E.cid = C.cid)
 FROM Courses C
 GROUP BY C.dept
```

But I can't figure out how to get the MAX-COUNT syntax to work properly.  I've tried a lot of different examples from Google and StackOverflow and none of them worked for me.  MySQL says the syntax is wrong.

Comment: Where is your `Courses` table?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the query off the top of my head.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like nested queries for this kind of problem.  First select the enrollment counts grouped per class.  Then find the max enrollment count grouped per department:

```
SELECT MAX(cnt) cnt, dept FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, dept, C.cid
    FROM Courses C 
        INNER JOIN Enrollment E on C.cid = E.cid
    GROUP BY cid, dept
) a
GROUP BY dept
```

Comment: Thanks, what was wrong with the query I wrote?  Is this just a difference between SQL and MySQL?

Comment: I think there are a few things wrong with the query.  For one: for aggregate statements, each column you select has to be either an aggregate function or in the group by clause.  So "select name, max(something) group by dept" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no declaration of E, so you can't use E.cid

So, either you do this

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(c.*) as count 
FROM Courses C
GROUP BY C.dept
```

Or,

```
 SELECT c.name, MAX(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Enrollment E WHERE E.cid = C.cid)
 FROM Courses C
 GROUP BY C.dept
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT c.name, COUNT(E.*) AS cnt FROM Enrollment E
    INNER JOIN Courses C ON E.cid = C.cid
    GROUP BY C.dept
) final
```