# Relational Database - Finding instructors who taught the most courses in 2009

Tags: relational-algebra

We have the following schema:

```
instructor(ID, name, dept name, salary)
teaches(ID, course id, sec id, semester, year)
```

Find instructors who taught the most courses in 2009. Can someone please help me? I'm confused how to write this out in relational algebra.

Comment: How can you get `the most courses` in relational algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be homework ;-)  So I'll give you some hints...

Since I haven't done tuple relational calculus since college (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra), here is an approximation in sql,

```
select instructor.ID, instructor.name, count(teaches.ID)
from instructor
join teaches on teaches.ID = instructor.ID
and count(teaches.ID) >= ...
group by ...
```

Leaving you to fill in the group by and >= values.

Think about how you calculate how many courses each teacher teaches,

```
select teaches.ID, count(*)
from teaches
group by teaches.ID
```

This might help: [MySQL count maximum number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855810/mysql-count-maximum-number-of-rows)